# Showing the related data in Datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have two datatables: Transactions and Accounts.

Transaction has a foreign key IDAccount from Accounts dataTable.

I assign datasource property of Datasource property of Datagridview to Transactions dataTable.

I want to Accounts.description insead of IDAccount in Datagridview.

What must I do?

Answer (score 2):

Make the column in your DataGridView that's bound to the IDAccount field a [DataGridViewComboBoxColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.aspx) and set its properties as follows:

- DataSource: your Accounts DataTable
- DisplayMember: Description
- ValueMember: IDAccount

The `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`'s `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` properties allows you to store and manipulate your IDAccount value in your DGV (and data source) while displaying to the user the Description value.  The MSDN article I linked explains it well.

Comment: +1  Excellent answer!  In addition, they may wish to set the DisplayStyle property to "Nothing" so that the drop down button does not show on the column.

Comment: Thanks @Ken - I didn't know about that property. I might have to go back to a few projects and make some small changes...

Comment: This is good tactic if i use designer mode.
When i bound it in source code we can do that.

Is there another solution for this problem?

Comment: @Tabriz You can set these same properties programmatically too (you don't need the designer to do this).  Or is that not what you mean?