# Filtering related data in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter

I have a `DataGridView` that pulls data from a couple tables similarly to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678326/showing-the-related-data-in-datagridview) setup.  It works great.  Good post and answer.  Continuing with the example in that post, I now want to create a filter that yields all transactions in the `DataGridView` that apply to a specific account by using a `LIKE` parameter on the account description.

I have a solution by checking the accounts table for the description and obtaining the IDAccount value then using that value in the `DataGridView` filter, but I was hoping there would be a more automated way using bindings.

Any ideas?  Thank you for your suggestions.

**Edit**:
Supposing I have a `TextBox` control called AccountDescriptionBox, I'd like to be able to do something like

```
dataGridView1.Filter = string.Format("{0} LIKE '{1}'", "IDAccount", AccountDescriptionBox.Text);
```

Obviously, this won't work as IDAccount is an integer, not a string.  The solution I mention above is

```
string filter = string.Empty;
Regex searchTerm = new Regex(Regex.Escape(AccountDescriptionBox.Text).Replace('\\', '.'), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var accts = from acct in dataSet1.Accounts
            let matches = searchTerm.Matches(acct.Description)
            where matches.Count > 0
            select acct.ID;
for (int i; i < accts.Count() - 1; i++)
{
    filter += string.Format("IDAccount = {0} OR ",accts.ElementAt(i));
}
filter += string.Format("IDAccount = {0}",accts.Last());
dataGridView1.Filter = filter;
```

This works, but is cumbersome.  I'd rather do it through bindings if there's a way.

Comment: Code snippets to illustrate what it is you trying to accomplish may help

Comment: I have also been trying out how to filter datagridviews lately. In my case they were populated by linq. The solution I'm using now is to simply use the linq query as the filter, so the filtering happens before the rows end up in the datagridview. Might work for you depending on your situation.

Comment: Can you give a text exmaple AKA without using code of the real world statement as to what it is your require e.g. Resulting table should show: all doctors filtered by ones that have seen patient "John Smith"

Comment: If I have accounts named "Checking", "Savings", and "401(k)", I'd like to have the view only show transactions from account named "Savings".

Comment: Or, if I have accounts named "Checking1", "Checking2", and "Savings", I'd like to have the view show all transactions from accounts whose names match "Check*".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to do this directly with data bindings.  I posted the solution as an edit in response to @CodeBlend's comments.

Answer (score 1):

Check out DataView class. It allows you to sort and filter records and also perform simple SQL-like manipulations.

Comment: Thanks, but I already have the interface designed to such an extent that I don't want to change it.  I'll look at the other control when it's time to upgrade the software.

Comment: Rework your solution to save headaches if you revisit your code.  DataView is the correct solution and should be marked as such. Look at the [MSDN documentation for DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx)